# Fishpig Magento/Wordpress Integration Custom Post Types & Page Templates

Tags: wordpress, magento, integration, magento-1.6, fishpig

I've got Magento v1.6.2.0 CE and the latest version of the Fishpig Integration plug-in, how can I get custom page templates functionality to work? Currently it just displays, as it would any other page.

Also how I can I get the custom post types functionality to work also, currently it just 404's when I load it. I've used the correct rewrite slug and refreshed permalinks as standard, it works on a normal wordpress (with no integration).

If anyone could shed any light on this, it would be most appreciated, otherwise I'll have to go back to the drawing board and integrate this a different way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've used full integration - the reason nothing much seems to work in the Wordpress install is because all the theme files will be in base/default/templates/wordpress of your Magento installation (that's assuming that you installed it via Magento Connect).

Took me a bit of time to work that out the first time I hit it. I would say you'll have a bit of Magento work on your hands to get your custom post types to work, might even be quicker to go for partial integration and code up a Wordpress theme to match your Magento one.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

I'm going to go down the line of integrating magento header/footer into Wordpress, and do a partial integration.